# Using AngularJS with Kendo UI

Tags: angularjs, telerik, kendo-ui

I'm currently working on an AngularJS project. In this project, I need to use the Kendo UI components. I found the Kendo / AngularJS Directives [here](https://github.com/kendo-labs/angular-kendo). Unfortunately, I have been unable to get a date picker to work. Currently, I have the following code in a partial that I added to the sample app on the GitHub page:

```
<div>
  <b>Birth Date</b>

  <div id="theDate" ng-model="birthDate" kendo-date-picker k-format="MM/dd/yyyy"></div>
  <br />
  Current Choice: <div>{{birthDate}}</div>
</div>
```

When the user visits '/birth-date' (I setup a route in app.js), the view appears as desired. This view shows the date picker. However, when I choose a date, that date does not appear in the text field. For the sake of testing, I display the selected date below the date picker. I can see that value getting updated as I choose dates.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to work fine for me:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">    
  {{birthday}}
  <input kendo-date-picker ng-model="birthday" k-format="MM/dd/yyyy" />
</div>
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/UhAQabi/2